# Creating a function in php that checks that get value is in the order dd/mm/yyy

Tags: php

I'm currently building a room booking system and was wondering how to check if the user has entered a date (get value) in the correct UK format of dd/mm/yyyy.

```
$uk_date = $_GET["date"];
```

For example to avoid a situation where the user types in 12/2012 or 2012 or uses the incorrect separators.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiple ways. For example, explode() with '/' and then use checkdate().

Comment: Does it have to be a GET value? It would be cleaner to use a POST value combined with something like the [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), in which you can set the desired format. Set it to be read-only and the user has no other choice but to use your formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would be [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $uk_date);
$errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
if($errors['warning_count'] || $errors['error_count']) {
    // something went wrong, you can look into $errors to see what exactly
}
```

If the parsing is successful then you have in your hands a [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object that provides lots of useful functions. One of the most important is [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) which will let you get data out of the object, e.g.:

```
$year = $date->format('Y');
```

Comment: If he have pretty fresh PHP version. Which is not an option on a lot of shared hosts. (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

Comment: @Endijs: I am providing the best answer I can. If the OP cannot use it (I won't get into an argument here) they can say so and *then* we can provide alternatives. Also, FYI PHP 5.3.0 [was released on 30 June 2009](http://www.php.net/archive/2009.php), which I would not call "pretty fresh".

Comment: Whoops... seems like it _fixes_ invalid values. The invalid UK date `12/13/2012` was changed to `2013-01-12`.

Comment: @Jon: I hope i did not offend you. I just added comment, so that there would not follow comment like 'I tried, but this did not work-downvote'.

Comment: @SalmanA: Edited the answer to show how you can guard against that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Same question as above... will it be able to differentiate between the formats of 1/1/2012, 01/1/2012 1/01/2012 for example? PHP server uses version 5.3.6 btw.

Comment: @Endijs: I was not offended, but I also do not pay attention to such short-sighted downvotes whenever I get them.

Comment: @CJS: No, it will parse all of those as the same. But you could have tried it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex code like this:

```
$str = '12/12/2012';
$regex = '#^\d{1,2}([/-])\d{1,2}\1\d{4}$#';
if (preg_match($regex, $str, $m))
   echo "valid date\n";
```

Comment: Will it be able to differentiate between the formats of 1/1/2012, 01/1/2012 1/01/2012 for example?

Comment: and it will also return "valid date" for `99-99-2012`

Comment: @SalmanA: The OP's question is NOT to validate the date. As per OP `For example to avoid a situation where the user types in 12/2012 or 2012 or uses the incorrect separators.` If date validation is needed then an additional call to `checkdate` will do it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this function:

```
public static function CheckValidDate($sDate) {
    $sDate = str_replace('/', '-', $sDate);
    preg_match('/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/', $sDate, $xadBits);
    if ($xadBits)
      return checkdate($xadBits[2], $xadBits[1], $xadBits[3]);
    else
      return false;
}
```

Visit the reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Thanks for the comment @SalmanA

Comment: +1 for using checkdate (PS: don't forget to check if preg_match returned true or $xadBits is not null).

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
$pattern = '|^[\d]{,2}/[\d]{,2}/[\d]{,4}$|is';
if (preg_match($pattern, $date, $match)) {
  echo 'ok!';
}
```

Comment: Same question as above - will it be able to differentiate between the formats of 1/1/2012, 01/1/2012 1/01/2012 for example?

Comment: @CJS yes, i edited code and now it will work fine for all your examples

Comment: I've done this to check if $date does not match but it doesn't work (by using !preg_match instead of preg_match). `if (!preg_match($pattern, $date, $match)) {
 echo 'Wrong date format';
 exit;
}`